Adding new text field to GraphQL query causes null error on execution when template hasn't been updated
I added a new basic text field (newTextField) to a configuration template for my primary navigation in Sitecore, and I updated my GraphQL query to get the new field:
query HeaderNavigationQuery($language: String!, $navHeaderRoot: String!) {
  headerConfig: item(
    path: $navHeaderRoot # "{2EA0944F-61A1-48EB-9BD0-E30003473B44}"
    language: $language
) {
  ... on _HeaderNavConfiguration {
    headerNav: headerRoot {
      ... on LookupField {
        targetItem {
          ... on HeaderNavigation {
            logoLink {
              jsonValue
            }
            logoLarge {
              jsonValue
            }
            phoneNumber {
              jsonValue
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    primaryNav: primaryNavigationRoot {
      ... on LookupField {
        targetItem {
          ...primaryNavigation
        }
      }
    }
    newTextField: newTextField{
      jsonValue
    }
  }
 }
}

This all worked fine, but when promoting to our higher environments, I ended up getting an error on one of our sub-site navs in the alternate languages; because the GraphQL query was updated in the environment but the nav configuration item had not been republished, it returned null on the newTextField field, which caused a GraphQL error that broke the whole navigation. But this only happened with items that I hadn't republished in Spanish and Arabic; I didn't seem to have to republish the items in the default English
This is concerning to me because if I miss any item that needs to be republished, there could be a broken page that I'm not aware of. I wouldn't think that if the field is null it would return a GraphQL error - I would think that it would just give a null value for that field, which I could handle in code, but instead the code throws an error with the GraphQL Error during preload data for component - Unexpected Execution Error.
In my research it looks like GraphQL fields should be nullable by default, so why is it throwing an error before I republish the configuration item, and is there a way to prevent it from throwing an error if the field does not exist yet?
